# Templating with Java web app

Tags: java, templates, web-applications

I am working on a Java Web Application, specifically the view and the view-controller. My primary experience is in PHP (this is my first Java web app), and I have implemented several template-like tools that essentially used `include` to travel down the directory structure, building out the page. For example, a url like `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=customer/edit&customer_id=5` would begin on root/index.php. It would then include customer/index.php (where I would probably construct the customer object) and then include the edit.php page where the form would be.

Is there an include-like function in Java? The problem I am trying to solve is, I want the basic html of my site (header, middle, footer) to remain the same, as you travel through pages, generally you are just changing the main content section.

My initial thought would be use a servlet on index.jsp that would pass the request to the next servlet in the directory structure (index if the next item in the parameter is a directory, the page if it is a file). Is this a viable way of creating a small templating engine? I am not sure about the resource intensiveness of passing from one servlet to another to build the html pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your using? If 'JSP' you could use `<jsp:include page="..." />` 
Another good option is using [Apache Velocity templates](http://velocity.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Struts, you can use Struts Tiles. Struts Tiles allows you to define the template page and you can define headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Twig which is a PHP templating engine, then [Pebble](http://mitchellbosecke.com/pebble) could be exactly what you're looking for. Disclosure: I'm the author of Pebble.